# egit->eclipse proper import of general_project->Java_project

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-2.0, egit, deadbolt

I've checked out deadbolt-2-core with egit from repository.

Then I've imported it as "general project":

[image]

Then I've added to .project file:

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

and project started to look like:

[image]

Here the "app" should probably be the folder and "be.objectify.deadbolt.core" a module name.
How can I organize proper view of the project with all imports working and the project being ready to be referenced by other projects?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to EGit at all. It seems like you have added the project itself as a source folder, instead of `app`. To correct this, do the following:

1. Open the properties of the project
2. Go to *Java Build Path* > *Source*
3. Remove the project folder from the build path
4. Add the app folder to the build path

Comment: And maybe commit the .classpath and .project files?

Comment: @nitind Yes, in general these and .settings should be in the repository.